# what is the Ember implementation of setInterval and clearInterval

Tags: ember.js

Ember has the following implementation of `setTimeout`, which it is recommended developers use because the code gets added to the run loop, which has advantages for tests.

```
           Ember.run.later((function() {
               console.log("will run once after 1000");
           }), 1000);
```

Is there a similar Ember replacement for `setInterval` and, by implication, `clearInterval` (which is used to cancel a setInterval)?  I need to run `someFunc` every 1000 ms

```
this.intervalId = setInterval(this.someFunc.bind(this), 1000);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not aware of any equivalent, but I use such a code to have the functionality:

```
var Poller = Ember.Object.extend({

  _interval: 1000,
  _currentlyExecutedFunction: null,

  start: function(context, pollingFunction) {
    this.set('_currentlyExecutedFunction', this._schedule(context, pollingFunction, [].slice.call(arguments, 2)));
  },

  stop: function() {
    Ember.run.cancel(this.get('_currentlyExecutedFunction'));
  },

  _schedule: function(context, func, args) {
    return Ember.run.later(this, function() {
      this.set('_currentlyExecutedFunction', this._schedule(context, func, args));
      func.apply(context, args);
    }, this.get('_interval'));
  },

  setInterval: function(interval) {
    this.set('_interval', interval);
  }

});

export
default Poller;
```

Then, you instantiate the poller: `var poller = Poller.create()` and then you can play with `poller.start()` and `poller.stop()` + set set the interval via `poller.setInterval(interval)`.

In my code, I did more or less that way (polling the reports every 10 seconds):

```
_updateRunningReport: function(report) {
  var poller = new Poller();
  poller.setInterval(this.POLLING_INTERVAL);
  poller.start(this, function() {
    if (report.isRunning()) {
      this._reloadReport(report);
    } else {
      poller.stop();
    }
  });
  eventBus.onLogout(function() {
    poller.stop();
  });
},
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: This is beautiful code. Thank you. Just to make sure I'm using it correctly, I pasted your answer (exactly as you wrote it) into my file, created an instance, and then (this is the part I need help) called it from a controller passing `this` as the context, like this:  ` poller.start(this, this.queryFunction);` Is that how you envisioned I use it?

Comment: i.e.  Is that how you envisioned I use it i.e. calling it from a controller?

Comment: yes, this is exactly how I use it :) + I've got a listener for some actions to stop the poller

Comment: I took the idea from somewhere, it's not originally mine, just to be clear :)

Comment: ok, thanks, feel free to add the listener code if you think it fits with your answer. I'd be interested in seeing it.

Comment: so here I've got two cases - when the report is still running, refresh it, otherwise, stop polling; the other case is when I log out; the third case could be leaving the route for example. `eventBus` is my implementation of a regular Event Bus

Comment: Thanks; this was helpful. For use with a small interval, I recommend moving the `poller.stop()` logic into a state observer rather than checking `report.isRunning()` every poll.

Answer (score 3):

I have been playing around with implement "setInterval" in Ember Octane way and I think this is THE MOST SIMPLE and CLEAN solution:

index.hbs:

```
{{this.counter}}
<button {{on "click" this.start}}>Start</button>
<button {{on "click" this.stop}}>Stop</button>
<button {{on "click" this.reset}}>Reset</button>
```

controllers/index.js

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { tracked } from '@glimmer/tracking';
import { action } from '@ember/object';
import { cancel, later, next } from '@ember/runloop';

export default class IndexController extends Controller {
  @tracked counter = 0;
  runner = null;

  @action start() {
    next(this, function () {
      this.runner = this.tick();
    });
  }

  @action stop() {
    cancel(this.runner);
  }

  @action reset() {
    this.counter = 0;
  }

  tick() {
    return later(this, function () {
      this.counter++;
      this.runner = this.tick();
    }, 1000);
  }    
}
```

[image: result in browser]

Comment: It's possible to simplify if it's ok to execute tick logic at start: `tick() { this.counter++; return later(this, this.tick, 1000) }`

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the [ember-poll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-poll) add-on. Internally, it does somewhat the same as @andrusieczko Poller object (both take the Ember Run Loop into account). From an Ember developer view, you get access to a `poll` service.

Just install the add-on: `npm install ember-poll --save-dev`.

---

Example:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  poll: Ember.service.inject(),

  setupController() {
    this._super(...arguments);

    this.get('poll').addPoll({
      interval: 1000,
      label: 'my-poll',
      callback: () => {
        //do something every second
      }
    }); 
  },

  actions: {
    willTransition() {
      this.get('poll').clearPollByLabel('my-poll');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested in `ember -v 1.18`

This is what I've been doing inside my component. This works perfectly fine and should be the ideal way of approaching. If you're handling async  promise objects inside the interval, make sure to kill it in `willDestroyElement()` hook or somewhere.

```
init() {
  this._super(...arguments);
  this.startAutoSaveTimer();
},

startAutoSaveTimer() {
  let autosaveFunc = function() {
    console.info('Arr .. I'm a pirate!');
  };
  set(this, 'timerInstance', setInterval(autosaveFunc, 1000));
},
```