# How to specify setInterval in emberjs?

Tags: javascript, api, ember.js, frontend

I have a api call which need to be called every five seconds. I used setInterval in javascript to make api call in my dynamic web project. Now I am converting the entire frontend to emberjs , I am new to ember .Can anyone help me to resolve it.

Comment: kindly explain a specific problem, so that it will be easy for other developers to answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what is the Ember implementation of setInterval and clearInterval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28310414/what-is-the-ember-implementation-of-setinterval-and-clearinterval)

Answer (score 0):

There is a few useful addons, for any async logic for ember: https://ember-lifeline.github.io/ember-lifeline/docs/poll-task may be useful here, or http://ember-concurrency.com/docs/tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Polling every 35 seconds for changes of the resource that I use, as building a websocket would be an overkill for the usecase

```
  tick() {
   return later(this, function () {
       this.counter++;
       debounce(this, this.getResource, null, 0, 1000, true);
       this.runner = this.tick();
     }, 35000);
  },

  stopPolling() {
    if (this.runner) {
      cancel(this.runner);
    }
  },

  startPolling() {
    if (ENV.environment === 'development') {
      return;
    }

    next(this, function() {
      this.runner = this.tick();
    });
  },

  handleStartStopPolling() {
    if (document.hidden) {
      this.stopPolling();
    } else {
      this.startPolling();
    }
  },

  didInsertElement() {
    this.getResource();
    this.startPolling();
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the interval so if in JS you have something like this:

```
this.interval =setInterval(this.gameMoves, 1000);
```

In Ember it will look like so:

```
this.interval = setInterval(this.moveOutcomes.bind(this), 1000);
```

An alternative solution is to use later from [ember/runloop](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/functions/@ember%2Frunloop/later).
Here is an example of using later in a countdown:

```
import Component from '@glimmer/component';
import { tracked } from '@glimmer/tracking';
import { action } from '@ember/object';
import { later } from '@ember/runloop';

export default class extends Component {
  @tracked startTime = 5;
  @tracked isCounting = false;

  @action
  startCountdown() {
    this.isCounting = true;
    this.startTime = this.startTime - 1;

if (this.startTime <= 0) {
  this.startTime = 5;
  this.isCounting = false;
  return;
}

later(this, this.startCountdown, 1000);
  }
}
```